# Validator pattern not working Regex

Tags: regex, validation, angular, angular2-formbuilder

In angular version: 2.1.1, I've create a form with form builder, one controller is for inputting coordinates (latlng) from google maps. I've defined the coordinates format with regex as:

- (-?\d+(.\d+)?),\s*(-?\d+(.\d+)?)

Thus a valid string would be:

- 2.3, 4.66

I've set my validator as:

```
this.addressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  "geoLocationLatLng":[null, [
     Validators.required,
     Validators.maxLength(150), 
     Validators.pattern("(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)")]],
});
```

Question, why is pattern validation not working?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use `Validators.pattern("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?,\\s*-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")`

Comment: Also, why not use `Validators.pattern(/^-?\d+(\.\d+)?,\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/)`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew OMG, I've spent more than 3 hours on this, I've also upgraded angular2 library... and it was all down to escape characters, shame on me. Btw thanks. The correct sequence is (\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?),\\s*(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)

Comment: You do not need to escape the hyphens. `"-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?,\\s*-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"` should work, too. But doesn't `Validators.pattern(/^-?\d+(\.\d+)?,\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/)` work?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Answer the question so that I can vote you.

Comment: Actually, I think your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903488/javascript-backslash-in-variables-is-causing-an-error. Or better - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668544/javascript-a-backslash-as-part-of-the-string

Comment: nope (/^-?\d+(\.\d+)?,\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/) does not work